# Can't locate [mutt]'s `muttrc`

Tags: mutt

The config file for `mutt`, `muttrc`, is not where `mutt -h` says it should be. Could someone help?

```
~ $ mutt -v
Mutt 1.9.4 (2018-02-28)
Copyright (C) 1996-2016 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 6.1.20180127 (compiled with 6.1)
libidn: 1.33 (compiled with 1.33)
hcache backend: tokyocabinet 1.4.48

Compiler:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 

Configure options: '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=\${prefix}/include' '--mandir=\${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=\${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-mailpath=/var/mail' '--enable-compressed' '--enable-debug' '--enable-fcntl' '--enable-hcache' '--enable-gpgme' '--enable-lua' '--enable-imap' '--enable-smtp' '--enable-pop' '--enable-sidebar' '--enable-nntp' '--enable-dotlock' '--disable-fmemopen' '--with-curses' '--with-gnutls' '--with-gss' '--with-idn' '--with-mixmaster' '--with-sasl' '--without-gdbm' '--without-bdb' '--without-qdbm' '--with-tokyocabinet' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mutt-woklFX/mutt-1.9.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'

Compilation CFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mutt-woklFX/mutt-1.9.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security

Compile options:
-DOMAIN
+DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  +USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  +DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK   
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP  
-USE_SSL_OPENSSL  +USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  +USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO  
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX  
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET  
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  +CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME  
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR  
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE  +USE_SIDEBAR  +USE_COMPRESSED  
-ISPELL
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
MIXMASTER="mixmaster"
To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please visit <https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/issues>.

~ $ man mutt | grep 'muttrc' 
-F muttrc Specify an initialization file to read instead of ~/.muttrc ~/.muttrc or ~/.mutt/muttrc curses(3), mailcap(5), maildir(5), mbox(5), mutt_dotlock(1), muttrc(5), ncurses(3), sendmail(1),
~ $ [ -d .mutt ] && echo "found" || echo "missing"
missing
~ $ [ -f .muttrc ] && echo "found" || echo "missing"
missing
```

Comment: I've never used `mutt`, but are you don't have to create the `muttrc` file yourself? Most of the programs I can think of that can be configured with an rc file don't create one for you upon installation.

Comment: @Erwann Under Ubuntu 20.04 there is a sample muttrc file located: `/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/sample.muttrc-starter` which can be copied to `$HOME/.muttrc` and then edited as appropriate. In `/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/` you will see other 'starter' configuration files for colors, sidebar etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451381/160267) given by Gilles, you need to create that hidden file yourself in the "home" directory. So add a '.muttrc' file to complete your configuration setup.